# How to insert user table

Tags: users

I would like to know how I can show registered users in a table with profile pictures like this site has. I would like to make this kind of site where actors can make a profile so they are put in a actors user role and that I can give people who look for actors an other role, so they can look for them in the database and actors can't. I am kind of a newbie to this sorry for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) is typically how this kind of thing is done. There are options for outputting tables or unstyled divs that you can theme yourself.